# access 2010 relationship - one field to 2 in another table

Tags: ms-access, relational-database

I have 2 tables - Company and Invoice. 
Invoice has fields - number, supplier, buyer etc.
Company has fields - name, etc.
- I would like to store every company (suppliers and also buyers) in one table.
- When creating an invoice, I would like to use only table Company to reference supplier and buyer.
- Every company can be buyer/supplier on any invoice.

**Question1**: How to create such relationship between Company and Invoice? And is it even possible?
I understand this can be problematic because if want to create a query to show invoice number, supplier and buyer, there is only one field with company name in Company table. So it seems that the way to go is to have 2 tables (suppliers and buyers) as @Invent-Animate suggests. However, I do not want to keep 2 records of same company in 2 tables.(Every company can be buyer/supplier)
**Question2**: How to overcome this problem?
Thank you for your time

Comment: Suppliers and Buyers are two separate entities. Should be their own tables, respectively. Then, your Invoice table will have a Primary Key for each Invoice, and 2 foreign keys -> SupplierID and BuyerID

Comment: @Invent-Animate I understand but in my case, a buyer on one invoice can be supplier on another. So I want to keep all records in one table if possible. Or should I somehow keep 2 tables identical? Thank you

Comment: The 2 tables aren't identical because you said a buyer *can* be a supplier, not *will always be a supplier*. I think you could get by with 1 table, but I would go with 2 if I had the option. As far as your question is concerned, we need a picture of the relationship diagram or table schema or something.

Comment: @Invent-Animate I just do not want to keep records about one company in two tables. My workflow would be - insert some companies to company table and in Invoice table, choose any of companies from company table  as supplier and any of companies as a buyer.

Comment: What if a company discontinues its' buying or supplying services, but continues doing the other?

Comment: @Invent-Animate I do not see a problem with that, even if a company discontinues any service. I would simply stop referencing the company as a supplier or buyer. Or are here any caveats that I am missing?

Comment: If you feel strongly about your database design, then let's move on to you providing more information around your query issue by giving us a look at your table schema and/or a picture of your query builder/relationship diagram and some sample data.

Comment: @Invent-Animate The thing is that I do not feel strong at all with my design:) Thinking about it, the simplest method is what you suggest - to have 2 tables with suppliers and buyers. One thing to figure out would be to be able to update both tables when records in any of them changes.

Comment: Update the tables how? We are getting a little off topic of your question which is about your query, but if you want your question to be about database design I suggest editing your question and removing the query aspect and identifying what you need and what you aren't sure of. For instance, how would you need to update both tables? By adding a buyer/supplier? Making them inactive? Etc..

Comment: @Invent-Animate hi I updated my question, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

In this link I found my answer http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/948061-how-relate-two-fields-one-table-one-field-another
Basically it was very simple, I was just not aware of such functionality in access.